# I have an assignment to collate emails ids in a workbook that are present in several columns in an array and then paste it on a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an assignment to collate email ids that are present on several columns, some of the cells in the columns are blank also, get all the email ids stored in an array, then paste the array in a new file. Till now I have written the following code, however the same is not working, primarily due to the For Next loop and the If function, I am getting error such 'compile error:end if without block if'  any help to rectify the code would be appreciated:

```
Sub CopyPasteII()

    ' this is the source file path and name
    
    Const FPTH As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\Misc\XYZ.xlsx"
    
    Dim Swbk As Workbook, Swsht As Worksheet, Dwbk As Workbook, Dwsht As Worksheet
    Dim Sfname As String, EmlidList As String, Hname As String, R As Long, C As Long, R2 As Long
    Dim Acellrng As Range, rngPaste As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Dim arremailid() As Variant    
       
    'this is to set destination workbook and worksheet name
    
    Set Dwbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set Dwsht = Dwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'this is to set source workbook and worksheet name
    Set Swbk = Workbooks.Open((FPTH), ReadOnly:=True)
    Set Swsht = Swbk.Sheets("XYZ")
    
    'this 'For' loop is to loop in the names present in the destination file
    
    For R = 2 To Dwsht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    
        Sfname = Dwsht.Range("A" & R).Value    
        Swsht.Activate    
        Columns("A:DC").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DC$1925").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Sfname
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DC$1925").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="XYZ"

        'this for loop is to loop in the columns present in the source file        
        For C = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("M1").End(xlToRight).Column    
            Hname = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 12 + C).Value    
                           
            If Hname = "To" Then    
                'this for loop is to loop in the cells present in the source file                
                For R2 = 1 To Swsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 12 + C).End(xlUp).Row    
                    EmlidList = Swsht.Cells(12 + C, R2).Value                    
                    If Not IsEmpty(Swsht.Cells(12 + C, R2)) Then                    
                        If EmlidList = "" Then                        
                           EmlidList = Swsht.Cells(12 + C, R2).Value                           
                        Else                        
                           EmlidList = EmlidList & ";" & Swsht.Cells(12 + C, R2).Value                           
                        End If                     
                    End If                                    
            
                    arremailid = Split(EmlidList, ";")    
                    Dwsht.Activate                    
                    Dwsht.Cells(2, 3).Value = arremailid
                End If
                Next R2
                    
        Next C    
    Next R
    Swsht.ShowAllData       
End Sub
```

Comment: Check the placement of your `Next R2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
  If Hname = "To" Then
      For R2 = 1 To Swsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 12 + C).End(xlUp).Row
         
   End If
   Next R2
```

This "End If" should be after the "Next R2" statement.

Comment: @deepankarhaldar Because you `Dim arremailid() As Variant` but `Split` returns an array of the type `String`. You need to declare the array as `String` like `Dim arremailid() As String` or the variable as non-array variant `Dim arremailid As Variant`

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, the 'For Next' loop where I am using 'R2' is not working properly, therefore still getting type mismatch error at 'arremailid = Split(EmlidList, ";")'.